# Is it possible to control Dynamixel X series motors using Raspberry Pi?

Tags: dynamixel, ros-indigo, raspberrypi

[image: Rosanswers logo]

I am looking to use Dynamixel X series motors (XM-430) for a torque control application. Since they are supported by ROS, I wanted to know if I can use RPi to control them, or do I need to invest in a dedicated controller board like OpenCR?

I appreciate your help.

---

[Originally posted](https://answers.ros.org/question/329315/is-it-possible-to-control-dynamixel-x-series-motors-using-raspberry-pi?/) by [SB](https://answers.ros.org/users/44293/sb/) on ROS Answers with karma: 11 on 2019-07-26

Post score: 1

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[image: Rosanswers logo]

you can use the Pi. But you need a usb-rs485 or an ttl3.3v -> rs485 converter

---

Originally posted by [duck-development](https://answers.ros.org/users/22870/duck-development/) with karma: 1999 on 2019-07-26

This answer was **ACCEPTED** on the original site

Post score: 0